# Simulating data from linear equation in R

Tags: r

I have a linear regression of the form:

```
Y= B0 + B1*X1 + B2*X2 + Be*Xe
```

If I assume values for Beta `(0.38,0.27,0.10)` and also assume that `Xi` are normally distributed with `N(0,1)`.

How can I generate a dataset that will be a linear combination of these variables?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the formula above represents -- the Bi's in the equation are the Betas?  What are Be and Xe?

Comment: presumably `Be` is the standard error of the residuals -- but I agree that it would be useful if you defined it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
beta =c(0.38,0.27,0.10)
beta0 <- 1
N <- 10           
x <- matrix(rnorm(n=N*3) ,ncol=3) ## generate (x1,x2,xe)
y <- beta0 + x %*% beta
```

Comment: Thanks! Once I have this how can I use specific values of betas to predict Y ?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you can generate this with a simple expression:

```
Y <- .38 + .27 * rnorm(1000) + .10 * rnorm(1000)
```

which will give you a vector, `Y`, distributed based on the formula above.